# export list from bash script to python

Tags: python, bash, list, import, export

**In a python script I would like to use a variable from a bash script which contains a list.**

I did that as follows:
First of all, I've created a list in a bash script. Additionally, I changed the list format to a python one and finally I export the list:

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHONPATH=$(which python)

TDATES="080201 080523 080905 090116 090515 090828 091211 100416 100730 101112
        110311 110701 111014 120210 120601 120914 130111 130503 130809 131213
        140404 140725"

echo $TDATES > datei.txt
sed "s/ /\\', \\'/g" datei.txt | sed "s/^/[\\'/g" | sed "s/$/\\']/g" > tdates.txt
TDP=$(cat tdates.txt)

export TDP

rm tdates.txt datei.txt

# exec python script
${PYTHONPATH} plot.py
```

The 'sed' commands will chance the format from "080201 080523 ..." to ['080201', '080523', '...',]. In the python script I import the list with:

```
# plot.py
import os
TDATES = os.getenv('TDP')
print TDATES
```

The screen output looks like: ['080201', '080523', '...'] which is good, **BUT**
If I try to loop over 'TDATES' with

```
for i in TDATES:
    print i
```

I'll get

```
[
'
0
8
0
2
0
1
'
,
```

instead of

```
080201
080523
...
```

I can't figure out what I failed to notice. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change TDATES, it's perfectly parseable in python like it is. Your bash script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHONPATH=$(which python)
TDATES="080201 080523 080905 090116 090515 090828 091211 100416 100730 101112
        110311 110701 111014 120210 120601 120914 130111 130503 130809 131213
        140404 140725"
export TDATES
# exec python script
${PYTHONPATH} plot.py
```

Your python script would look like this:

```
import os
TDATES = os.getenv('TDATES')
for i in TDATES.split(' '):
    print i
```

Another alternative would be to not export the environment variable and in the bash script pass the `$TDATES` variable to the python script as input parameter:

```
${PYTHONPATH} plot.py ${TDATES}
```

Then in python you would do:

```
import sys
for i in sys.argv[1:]
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
TDATES = os.getenv('TDP')
```

assigns the value of the environment variable `TDP` to `TDATES` as a *string*. Iteration over a string will proceed one character at a time, hence your output. As an example:

```
>>> for c in "string":
...     print c
... 
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

What you need to do is parse the string `TDATES` into a Python list, then iterate over that list. One way to do this is with the `ast.literal_eval()` function:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> TDATES = literal_eval(os.getenv('TDP'))
>>> type(TDATES)
<type 'list'>

>>> for date in TDATES:
...     print date
080201
080523
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But how can I assign the TDP variable to TDATES as a _list_? Sorry, but I'm very new to python...

Comment: `TDATES = literal_eval(os.getenv('TDP'))` does that - it parses the value of the TDP environment variable and binds the result to `TDATES`. Because the input conforms to a list definition, literal_eval returns a list object, hence TDATES is of type list.